# Which one is sensor from IIO?

Tags: sensor, kernel, driver

I am looking for list of sensors [from the kernel drivers](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/tree/drivers/iio?h=v4.19.97). I am not sure which one is sensor and which one is not. Are all of them sensors? If not then how can I get those I mean is there any API available to get the list of sensors?

Thanks!

Comment: Can't see any relevance to the Pi.  Perhaps read https://wiki.analog.com/software/linux/docs/iio/iio

Comment: I got your point. By the way thanks for link! @joan